# Beautifulsoup, Python and HTML automatic page truncating?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to parse HTML pages. Unfortunately, for some pages (> 400K) BeatifulSoup is truncating the HTML content.

I use the following code to get the set of "div"s:

```
findSet = SoupStrainer('div')
set = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, parseOnlyThese=findSet)
for it in set:
    print it
```

At a certain point, the output looks like:

`correct string, correct string, incomplete/truncated string ("So, I")`

although, the htmlSource contains the string "So, I am bored", and many others. Also, I would like to mention that when I prettify() the tree I see the HTML source truncated.

Do you have an idea how can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: chance is that the html is malformed. Post the relevant html.

Comment: @nosklo: Over 400K?  Perhaps a bad idea.  Post proof that the page is not malformed would be nicer.  Or post proof that the app is actually reading the entire page would be nicer.

Comment: BeautifulSoup tries to handle malformed markup, but yes, I'm sure it can be defeated eventually.  Try running the source HTML through http://validator.w3.org and that should pinpoint the invalid bits (there will very likely be tons of them)

Comment: Hi, this a page: http://voinici.ceata.org/~sana/test.html

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't care downloading 400k. It's small file, when comparing to my disk space and internet connection.

Comment: @nosklo: Small for you, but perhaps large to post as part of a question here.

Comment: I had the same problem with bs4 on Webpages that are not malformed, such as: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Game_theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`lxml.html`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html). It is a faster, better html parser, and deals better with broken html than latest BeautifulSoup. It is working fine for your example page, parsing the entire page.

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse('http://voinici.ceata.org/~sana/test.html')
print len(doc.findall('//div'))
```

Code above returns 131 divs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem using BeautifulSoup at [beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761164/beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html), because I think it is easier than lxml.

The only thing you need to do is to install:

```
pip install html5lib
```

and add it as a parameter to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```