# BeautifulSoup not extracting all html (automatically deleting much of a page's html)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract the contents from a website (http://brooklynexposed.com/events/). As an example of the problem I can run the following code:

```
import urllib
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://brooklynexposed.com/events/'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
```

The output seems to cut off the html as follows:

```
       <li class="event">
        9:00pm - 11:00pm
        <br/>
        <a href="http://brooklynexposed.com/events/entry/5432/2013-07-16">
         Comedy Sh
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is cutting off the listing with the name Comedy Show along with all html that comes after until the final closing tags. Majority of the html is being automatically removed. I have noticed similar things on numerous website, that if the page is too long, BeautifulSoup fails to parse the entire page and just cuts out text. Does anyone have a solution for this? If BeautifulSoup is not capable of handling such pages, does anyone know any other libraries with functions similar to prettify()?

Comment: For me, the entire content is there. Starting with your code to create the `soup` object: `>>> len(unicode(soup))` returns `107578` Which version of BS are you using? I am using 4.2.0.

Comment: Your code works for me just fine. If the network transfer was interrupted at that exact point (so you only loaded up until `Comedy Sh`) then the HTML parser will 'close' all still-open tags and you see exactly what you got.

Comment: Interesting, I was using 4.2.1 with Python 2.7. However when I use 3.2 it seems to work. It couldn't have been a timeout issue because if I printed the original HTML to a file then all of the text appeared. Any other ideas on a solution for 2.7? Otherwise it's time to start porting my code.

Comment: Different HTML parser used? BeautifulSoup will use the 'best' parser available, so if `lxml` is installed that'll be used for example. Different parsers handle broken HTML differently. You may want to run the [`.diagnose()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#troubleshooting) to see what BeautifulSoup tells you about that. If you cannot figure out what that tells you, paste the output here in your question.

Comment: Not sure if you figured it out or not, but it worked fine for me with beautiful soup 4.1.1 and python 2.7. I upgraded to 4.3.1 and it still worked.

Comment: I guess this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761164/beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

I had troubles that bs4 cuts html on some machines and on some not. It was not reproducable....

I switched to this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

.. and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me, but I get error when I say `soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')`

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> 
>>> import urllib
>>> url = 'http://brooklynexposed.com/events/'
>>> html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
>>> 
>>> 
>>> soup = bs(html)
>>> soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8788: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
>>> soup.prettify()
'<!doctype html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7 ]&gt; 
&lt;html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"&gt; &lt;![endif]-->\n
<!--[if IE 7 ]&gt;
...
...
...
...
</body>\n</html>\n'
```

.
.
.
.
I guess this may help you: [BeautifulSoup, where are you putting my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761164/beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html?rq=1)