# BeautifulSoup and Large html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, large-files, scrape

I was trying to scrape a number of large Wikipedia pages like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Game_theory).

Unfortunately, `BeautifulSoup` is not able to work with such a large content, and it truncates the page.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem using BeautifulSoup at [beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761164/beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html), because I think it is easier than lxml.

The only thing you need to do is to install:

```
pip install html5lib
```

and add it as a parameter to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html5lib')
```

However, if you prefer, you can also use lxml as follows:

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Game_theory')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the html content and then pass it to BS:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Game_theory')
if r.ok:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
  # get the div with links at the bottom of the page
  links_div = soup.find('div', id='catlinks')
  for a in links_div.find_all('a'):
    print a.text
else:
  print r.status_code
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing, but without the 'html5lib' parameter, there is no id='catlinks' in the content!

Comment: There is in my browser (<div id='catlinks' class='catlinks'>.....) Anyway, look at the source code in firefox/chrome, look for an element towards the bottom of the page and try to find it/extract it using BS.

Comment: I did the exact same thing. Do you think it might be related to the Python version (2.7), OS (WIN 8), ...? I don't think it is related to the browser, because I checked the actual html code generated by BeautifulSoup.prettify and it is incomplete.

Comment: I can confirm the code I wrote above doesn't work in windows 7, but does in Linux using python 2.7. Weird..