# HTML parsing gives wrong result

Tags: python, character-encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in Python to get some data from a table on a website. The soup object looks wrong. My code looks like this:

```
url =r'http://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all'
source_code = requests.get(url)
text= source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
```

When I look at tags in soup I found that the result looks wrong. I think I found the part that causes the problem. The original source code of that part looks like this:

```
<tr><td class="data">81</td>
<td><a href="/box-office-chart/daily/2010/05/07">5/7/2010</a></td>
<td><b><a href="/movie/Iron-Man-2#tab=summary">Iron Man 2</a></td>
<td class="data">$170,000,000</td>
<td class="data">$312,128,345</td>
<td class="data">$623,256,345</td>
<tr>
```

But printing out that part in soup it becomes:

```
<tr><td class="data">81</td>
<td><a href="/box-office-chart/daily/2010/05/07">5/7/2010</a></td>
<td><b><a href="/movie">/ I r o n - M a n - 2 # t a b = s u m m a r y " 
&gt;       I r o n   M a n   2 / a &gt; / t d &gt; 
t d   c l a s s = " d a t a " &gt; $ 1 7 0 , 0 0 0 , 0 0 0 / t d &gt; 
t d   c l a s s = " d a t a " &gt; $ 3 1 2 , 1 2 8 , 3 4 5 / t d &gt; 
t d   c l a s s = " d a t a " &gt; $ 6 2 3 , 2 5 6 , 3 4 5 / t d &gt; 
t r &gt;
```

Looks like there is an added quotation mark, and it caused BeautifulSoup to not recognize any more tags after that. 
How can I fix it? I tried Python's html parser and lxml. They gave the same result.

Comment: I'm not following, what do you mean? Could you post your code and tell us exactly what you want to capture?

Comment: I added more details. I hope it's easier to follow. Basically I want to read some data from a table on a webpage. But BS only properly read part of it and didn't read the rest of the rows.

Comment: the url = r'some_url.com' doesn't help since we can't see how the webpage is organized and not to mention you still didn't tell us exactly what data you wanted from the table. do you want year? movie title?

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a bunch of things, this is what I found. I tried cutting out the problematic part of the html code, but the result shows the problem at the same location. So I thought it might be length issue. I don't know if there is some kind of limit to html code for parsing in BS.

I found this similar question: [BeautifulSoup, where are you putting my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761164/beautifulsoup-where-are-you-putting-my-html?lq=1)

Installing and using 'html5lib' parser worked.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5lib")
```

The new result shows all the rest of the tags in soup.